# AndEngine can't login to google play service

Tags: android, andengine, google-play-services

I have followed every step in the tutorials and did everything. Now when I run my application, the google play login appears and it starts signing in but after few moments I get this dialog

[image]

I noticed that when I run my app using `Eclipse` directly I get a `Sha1 key` that starts with `67:xxxxxx` and when I export my `.apk` and then run it I get a different `sha1 key`, that starts with `B4:xxxxx`.

I have added both `sha1 keys` to my developer console, but this dialog still appears.

**Note that in the projects overview in the developer console, I can see 5 requests and 5 errors.**

My **manifest** codes:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

My **logcat**:

```
03-14 16:45:08.023: W/GameHelper(3839): **** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
03-14 16:45:08.023: W/GameHelper(3839): **** This is usually caused by one of these reasons:
03-14 16:45:08.023: W/GameHelper(3839): **** (1) Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match
03-14 16:45:08.023: W/GameHelper(3839): ****     the client ID you registered in Developer Console.
03-14 16:45:08.023: W/GameHelper(3839): **** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered.
03-14 16:45:08.023: W/GameHelper(3839): **** (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are 
03-14 16:45:08.023: W/GameHelper(3839): ****     trying to log in with an account that is not listed as
03-14 16:45:08.023: W/GameHelper(3839): ****     a test account.
03-14 16:45:08.023: W/GameHelper(3839): ****
03-14 16:45:08.023: W/GameHelper(3839): **** To help you debug, here is the information about this app
03-14 16:45:08.023: W/GameHelper(3839): **** Package name         : com.xxx.xx
03-14 16:45:08.031: W/GameHelper(3839): **** Cert SHA1 fingerprint: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
03-14 16:45:08.031: W/GameHelper(3839): **** App ID from          : xxxxxxx
03-14 16:45:08.031: W/GameHelper(3839): ****
03-14 16:45:08.031: W/GameHelper(3839): **** Check that the above information matches your setup in 
03-14 16:45:08.031: W/GameHelper(3839): **** Developer Console. Also, check that you're logging in with the
03-14 16:45:08.031: W/GameHelper(3839): **** right account (it should be listed in the Testers section if
03-14 16:45:08.031: W/GameHelper(3839): **** your project is not yet published).
03-14 16:45:08.031: W/GameHelper(3839): ****
03-14 16:45:08.031: W/GameHelper(3839): **** For more information, refer to the troubleshooting guide:
03-14 16:45:08.031: W/GameHelper(3839): ****   http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting
```

Also, I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but I get this too

```
03-14 16:45:01.960: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3839): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

I followed this tut: http://dola-software.tk/implementing-google-play-game-services-leaderboards-and-achievements-in-andengine-game/

Comment: Are you sure you imported the correct `R` class into the `BaseGameUtils` classes?

Comment: When you run the application from eclipse, apk is signed with debug keystore. When apk is exported, it is signed with release keystore. Hence the difference in SHA1. Try running from eclipse and ensure you copy the SHA1 generated from this command : `$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v`. Let me know whether it works.

Comment: Are both SHA1 added to same client ID? Can you try adding them to different client IDs?

Comment: This is how they are added now https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48748692/654.PNG

Comment: Have you enabled your account for testing? If not please follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub#enabling_accounts_for_testing).

Comment: i could see in the source code present in BaseGameUtils.zip, has lot of debug statements. can u post more logcat contents especially the logs before the one you have already shared.

Comment: The pastebin contents got deleted. Can you share one more time?

Comment: Based on the [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48748692/654.PNG) shared in a comment, I feel you have used Google Developer Console to generate client ID. Am I right? Instead you need to use Google Play Developer Console. Please read this [steps](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_3_generate_an_oauth_20_client_id)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the logs. By the way did you check my last comment?

Comment: I have fixed it thanks to you, cuz u gave me hope and your comments made me realize that I need to create from google play developer console. post an answer and ill accept it before 20 hrs please!

Comment: Happy to know that you could resolve the issue. I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48748692/654.PNG) shared in one of your comment, I believe you are using Google Developers Console to generate the client ID. 
**Google Play Developer Console should be used to generate the client ID.**

Please follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_3_generate_an_oauth_20_client_id) to generate the OAuth 2.0 client ID. Here is the one of the comment mentioned in that documentation:

> Warning: Do not create new client IDs for your game from the Google
>   Developers Console. If you do so, Play Games services will not
>   associate your game settings with the client ID, and this could cause
>   errors during gameplay.